# What is the issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a simple Simon says game which is not complete.
My problem is that IDLE 3.4 says that I have a problem when I can't see what it would be.

My code (with a walkthrough):

```
#Simple pattern repeating game
#Randomly chooses a pattern then user has to repeat

import random

poss = [int(1), int(2), int(3), int(4)]
#Sets possible choices
pattern = []
#Sets an array for the pattern to be contained in
plyr = []
#Sets an array for the players pattern to be contained in

def game ():
#Makes a function for the game to be played
    pattern.append(random.choice(poss))
    #Adds a new value to the game pattern every time
    for i in pattern:
    #Loops through the pattern
        print(i)
        #Prints the pattern you need to copy
        #For testing it sticks but this is to be change


    for i in pattern :
    #Loops through the pattern so you can give your value
        plyr[i] = int(input("Pattern part " + (i + 1) + " is?")
        #Gets your input of that value in the pattern

if(plyr == pattern):
#Checks if your pattern is right
    game()
    #Continues the game
```

My problem is at the `if` statement, it comes up that the colon (:) is wrong.

Does any one know what the problem is?

Comment: The game only appends one value to the argument. What is the point of the loops?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The first loop is what "simon says" the second loop takes your input

Comment: Yes but you only append one value to the pattern.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi its meant to work by repeating the previous pattern but adding an extra value every turn, so first round could be 1, then, 1, 2, then 1,2,3 etc So i save all the values to to the global array pattern so then extra values can be appended

Comment: What won't? Stack Overflow or your program?

Comment: I don't know. They have a lot of stupid policy. Can't edit a comment after five seconds. Have to earn reputation to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parentheses on the preceding line:

```
plyr[i] = int(input("Pattern part " + (i + 1) + " is?")
#            1     2                  3     3         2?
```

The `int()` call is not properly closed. Because Python allows extending the logical line to the next closing parenthesis, the next line is part of the expression, and only by the time you get to the colon is the error apparent.

You'll next find that `i + 1` produces an integer and cannot be summed with strings. You'd want to add a `str()` call:

```
plyr[i] = int(input("Pattern part " + str(i + 1) + " is?"))
```

or use string formatting:

```
plyr[i] = int(input("Pattern part {} is?".format(i + 1))
```

Because `plyr` is empty, this will raise an `IndexError`; you cannot alter indices that are not in the list. You probably meant to **append** new elements to the list instead:

```
player_guess = int(input("Pattern part {} is?".format(i + 1))
plyr.append(player_guess)
```

This takes the player guess into a new variable (easier to read) and appends that result to the `plyr` list.

Comment: `i+1` is an int, can't be added to strings.

Comment: Holy crap thats embarrasing, thankyou

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, Yeah i seen that when i went  back to python, fixed it now, thankyou!

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do i accept?

Comment: Is that your secret to such a high reputation Martijn?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Well if you ask me it's doing him justice lol

Comment: Yeah, I'm just joking around, but I have a great amount of respect for him. Only a high schooler, but I hope to be as good as him someday. Glad I could help him.

Comment: @Ashmoreinc: looks like you figured it out. :-)

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Whose just a highschooler?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ha, yeah :)

Comment: I am a high schooler. And what's so funny?

Answer (score 1):

your code have some wrongs, missing some close parenthesis. I did one version for you see:

```
import random

poss = [int(1), int(2), int(3), int(4)]
# Sets possible choices
pattern = []
# Sets an array for the pattern to be contained in
plyr = []
# Sets an array for the players pattern to be contained in

def game():
    # Makes a function for the game to be played
    pattern.append(random.choice(poss))
    # Adds a new value to the game pattern every time
    for i in pattern:
        # Loops through the pattern
        print(i)
        # Prints the pattern you need to copy
        # For testing it sticks but this is to be change

    for i in pattern:
        # Loops through the pattern so you can give your value
        plyr[i] = int(input("Pattern part {} is?".format(i + 1)))
        # Gets your input of that value in the pattern

if plyr == pattern:
    # Checks if your pattern is right
    game()
```

Comment: Thank You, I've had a look through and have now made the necessary changes, I know have some further issues so im going to changes to the original question so have a look at that soon

Comment: @Ashmoreinc: rather than change your question (making all answers instantly invalid), you would ask a new question. Do simplify your problem though, try to provide a [minimal example demonstrating your immediate issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than post all your code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Last time i did that i got blocked from asking questions for 5 days and okay I'll keep that in mind for next time. have a look now, theres more

Comment: @Ashmoreinc: if you put a bit more work into your questions so they show research effort and provide us with a proper code example, you won't get downvoted and blocked. I reverted your edit, please don't extend and break the Q&A format.

Comment: @Ashmoreinc: take into account that questions here are meant to be helpful to future visitors too, not just to you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True! I'll make a seperate Question now

Comment: @Ashmoreinc: I've updated my answer to address the other traceback you got.